# "Lectures of Riemann Surfaces" , $O$. Forster: Why do we need to solve the Dirichlet Problem on relatively compact domains?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, boundary-value-problem

When generalizing the Dirichlet Boundary Problem from the disk to a general Riemann Surface $X$, Forster solves to problem for:

> on all domains Domains $D \in X$ which are relatively compact and that are contained in a chart $(U,z)$, so that $z(D) \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a disk.

The reasoning, according to Forster, is that harmonic functions are invariant under biholomorphic mappings.

So, I assume the way Forster is generalizing the problem, is by projecting it by a biholomorphic mapping onto a disk in $\mathbb{C}$, solving it there the way it was solved in the pages before, and then returning to the Riemann-Surface by using another biholomorphic mapping.
Is that correct?
There is never a meantioning on how the problem is generalized.

If it works the way I just described, then it makes sense to me, that we want $z(D)$ to be a disk. What I do not understand though, is why it is necessary for $D$ to be relatively compact.

What problems would arise if we did no assumed that $D$ is relatively compact?

An answer would really help me to understand the rest of the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

The collection of harmonic and/or holomorphic functions on unbounded regions in $\mathbb C$ behaves significantly differently from those on a bounded region in $\mathbb C$.

The prototype for where we'd like to construct harmonic (or holomorphic) functions is the unit disk... as opposed to a disk with a part going out to infinity. Perhaps the Phragmen-Lindelof illustrates some aspect of this: the maximum modulus principle is not quite correct on a strip or half-strip... without a growth condition.